# Why do some write sometimes go faster than expected for MEDIUMTEXT

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, insert

We are running a MySQL Innodb database, our server has 4gb memory.  We are trying to improve the speed at which a 800KB XML File is stored in a `MEDIUMTEXT` column.  Currently, we have this query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `API_LogApiRequest`(sRequest 
  MEDIUMTEXT, sResponse MEDIUMTEXT)

BEGIN
   DECLARE sUUID VARCHAR(36);
   SELECT UUID() INTO sUUID;

   INSERT INTO ApiRequest
   (
       Id,
       Request,
       Response
   )
   VALUES
   (
       sUUID,
       sRequest,
       sResponse
   );

   SELECT sUUID AS 'UUID';
END;
```

The `sResponse` data can be as much as 800kb, and we are seeing it takes the following on 10 repeat calls.  These calls were all made with the same data.

> 0.687 sec
>
> 0.078 sec
>
> 0.188 sec
>
> 0.718 sec
>
> 0.047 sec
>
> 0.031 sec
>
> 0.610 sec
>
> 0.313 sec
>
> 0.141 sec
>
> 0.032 sec

Here is the Innodb status

```
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 560 merges
merged operations:
insert 560, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 49919, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 23.83 non-hash searches/s

----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 25772032; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 130139
Buffer pool size   1536
Free buffers       1024
Database pages     511
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  11
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1902256, not young 73968112
3.33 youngs/s, 52.77 non-youngs/s
Pages read 23821066, created 4126940, written 19043946
25.28 reads/s, 6.89 creates/s, 41.11 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 903 / 1000, young-making rate 12 / 1000 not 204 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 
0.00/s
LRU len: 511, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3805]:cur[242], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread id 7228, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 1340396, updated 304, deleted 1287534, read 12921295
2.78 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 1.33 deletes/s, 4.11 reads/s
```

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `ApiRequest` (
 `ApiRequestId` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Request` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Response` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `EventTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ApiRequestId`),
  KEY `IDX_EventTime` (`EventTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

What do I need to change to improve the performance?

Comment: Where is `sUUID` set?

Comment: Were the 10 calls with the _same_ data?  Or radically different sized data?

Comment: `sUUID` is set at the beginning of the SP `SELECT UUID() INTO sUUID`.  Those 10 calls were all made with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer goes something like this...

Approach 1:  800KB takes a lot of disk activity to write.  This takes perhaps 1000ms.  When you "wrote" a row in 31ms, that was because of most of the I/O being delayed until after acknowledging the action.  When it took 718ms, the disk was busy writing other things, so it was slow at accepting the current row.

Approach 2:  A rule of thumb for I/O with a HDD is 100/second.  800KB = 50 * 16KB blocks to write (plus some overhead).  That would compute out to 500ms per row.  So 718ms sounds a little high, and 31ms sounds like a lot of caching going on.

So the question should be "Why does this write sometimes go faster than expected?